# Flatten directory structure and mangle names for targets with make (or how to pair up two lists of files?)

Tags: makefile

**The X Problem**

Imagine we have a source code tree in the Mega langauge like so:

```
src/
   foo.mega
   utils/
       bar.mega
```

We'd now like to use the MegaDoc tool to generate documentation for each file, but only if it has been updated, like so:

```
docs/
   foo.html
   utils.bar.html
```

That is, we want a flat folder structure for the documentation. The naming rules of the Mega language ensures we will get no name clashes, so that's all fine.

The MegaDoc tool can only generate **one** doc file at the time.

```
megadoc input.mega -of output.html
```

How on Earth, would we set this up in a Makefile?

---

**The Y Problem**

I've gotten this far:

```
MG_FILES = ${shell find src -name *.mega -type f}

HT_FILES = $(subst .mega,.html,$(MG_FILES))
HT_FILES := $(subst /,.,$(HT_FILES))
HT_FILES := $(addprefix docs/,$(HT_FILES))

MG_FILES := $(addprefix src/,$(MG_FILES))
```

So in general `MG_FILES` is

```
src/foo.mega src/utils/bar.mega
```

and `HT_FILES` is

```
docs/foo.html docs/utils.bar.html
```

Seems so promising! But now I'm just stuck. I've tried some embarrasing things, that I won't show, that didn't work involving all kinds of `$@` and what not.

How do I get make to understand these two lists of files are supposed to match up and execute a series of commands on each pair, or something?

(Note: In reality, the source code folder is several levels deep.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use an implicit rules to do this: the patterns are too complex.  You'll need to use one of two methods: either auto-generated makefiles, or else use `$(eval ...)`.  I think the auto-generated makefile is simpler to understand.  Unfortunately I don't have a good idea of how to determine when to rebuild the makefile, so in that sense `$(eval ...)` is more straightforward.

Using `$(eval ...)` would look like this:

```
MG_FILES := ${shell find src -name *.mega -type f}

define MEGARULE
doc/$(subst /,.,$1).html: src/$1.mega
        megadoc $$< -of $$@
endef

$(foreach M,$(patsubst src/%.mega,%,$(MG_FILES),$(eval $(call MEGARULE,$M)))
```